# django ImageField not displaying, throws ImportError

Tags: python, django

I have a model where I have an image name, image description, and an image. I want to use these fields to display a div with the image description and name with the thumbnail for each row in my model. Right now when I am trying to render the template I am getting:

```
    TypeError: 'ImageFieldFile object is not subscriptable

    During handling of the above exception another error occured:

    ImportError: No module named 'backends'
```

Code:

Models.py

```
class PictureType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='AppName/images/')
```

views.py

```
class indexView(generic.ListView):
    model = PictureType
    template_name = 'index.html'
```

index.html

```
{% for visual in object_list %}
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="#" class="">
            <div align="center" class={{ visual.name }}>
                <h4 class="">{{ visual.name }}</h4>
                <p class="">{{ visual.description }}
                </p>
            </div>
           <img src= "{{ visual.image.url }}" alt="..." class="">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', indexView.as_view(), name = 'index'),
]
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

UPDATE:
When I change:

```
<img src= "{{ visual.image.url }}" alt="..." class="">
```

to

```
<img src= "{{ visual.image }}" alt="..." class="">
```

I don't get the above errors but the images don't come through either, they look like this:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to import 'backends' module somewhere in your code, but it does not exist in the python path.
Hope this was helpful.

Comment: I do have 'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates', in my settings.py.

Comment: Well it needs to be spelled 'backends' **exactly** if you want to import it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tecth the Image URL from DataBase and Pass it to your HTML template file as context data type.

first you have to make sure that, you have been installed Pillow Library
(pip instal pillow)

And load static files to index.html file
{% load static %} - use this code on the begining of HTML

then change your view.py Function to :

```
 class indexView(generic.ListView):
model = PictureType
users = PictureType.objects.all()
args = {'users':users}
template_name = 'index.html',args
```

## or better way to Pass the data is change your Views as Function.

```
def indexView(request):
model = PictureType
users = PictureType.objects.all()
args = {'users':users}
return render(request,"index.html", args)
```